# Name of the field increment issues which is dynamically generating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Codeigniter but my issue is not related to Codeigniter. I am getting some issues in my jQuery.

On page load, I am displaying the `Add more` button so when the user clicks on `Add more` then it will display the dropdown dynamically. (**Note**: The second dropdown will display from ajax success. So now I am displaying only text for understanding).

Below are the two dropdowns.

[image]

Now if you choose from the dropdown then it will display dynamically input field some think like this

[image]

The user can add more one the dropdown field only clicking on `Add more`.

check below image

[image]

Now my main issue is, I increment the name of the input field but not getting increment value. I am getting the below output

**For example**

First dropdown

```
<select name="pp_fileStatus2" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus dynamicVal"><option value="" disabled="" selected="">Status</option>//dropdown option</select>

<input type="text" name="reasonDate2" class="form-control datetimepicker" placeholder="Date">
```

Second dropdown

```
<select name="pp_fileStatus2" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus dynamicVal"><option value="" disabled="" selected="">Status</option>//dropdown option</select>
<input type="text" name="reasonDate2" class="form-control datetimepicker" placeholder="Date">
```

Notice here every time  i am getting `name="pp_fileStatus2"` for  every dropdown and `name="reasonDate2"` for every input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
  var count = 2;
  var numberIncr = 1; // used to increment the name for the inputs
  var addrm = '';

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "/access_control/getRMname",
    //data: {},
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(response) {
      addrm += '<select name="addrm' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect dynamicVal"><option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>';
      $.each(response, function(key, data) {
        addrm += '<option value="' + data.rmid + '">' + data.rmfirstname + ' ' + data.rmlastname + '</option>';
        //rm_details.push(addrm);
      });
      addrm += '</select>';
    }
  });


  //Once add button is clicked
  $(document).on('click', '#clicktoadd', function() {
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++; //Increment field counter
      $(".medication_info").append('<select name="pp_fileStatus' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus dynamicVal"><option value="" disabled selected>Status</option><option value="1">Open</option><option value="2">Close</option><option value="3">Pending</option></select><p>One more dropdown. It will come from ajax</p>' + addrm);
    }
    count++;

  });
  $(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus', function(event) {


    if (($(this).val() == '1') || ($(this).val() == '3')) {
      $(".medication_info").append('<div class="addbankField input-wrapper padding0"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="reasonDate' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control datetimepicker" placeholder="Date"></div></div><div class="addbankField input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="reasonAmt' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control commnumber" placeholder="amt"></div></div><input type="hidden" name="remark' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control" placeholder="Remark">');
    } else {
      $(".medication_info").append('<div class="addbankField input-wrapper lbpflex padding0"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="reasonDate' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control datetimepicker" placeholder="Date"></div></div><div class="addbankField input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="remark' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control" placeholder="Remark"></div></div><input type="hidden" name="reasonAmt' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control" placeholder="amt">');
    }
  });

  numberIncr++;

});
```

```html
<div id="clicktoadd"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-bg">Add More</a></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medication_info">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment value inside the `.click` callback since you are generating form name inside the `.click` event.

Increment `numberIncr` when you trigger a click. Also remove `numberIncr++` at the end script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxField = 10; //Input fields increment limitation
  var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1
  var count = 2;
  var numberIncr = 1; // used to increment the name for the inputs
  var addrm = '';

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "/access_control/getRMname",
    //data: {},
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function(response) {
      addrm += '<select name="addrm' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect dynamicVal"><option value="" selected disabled>Select</option>';
      $.each(response, function(key, data) {
        addrm += '<option value="' + data.rmid + '">' + data.rmfirstname + ' ' + data.rmlastname + '</option>';
        //rm_details.push(addrm);
      });
      addrm += '</select>';
    }
  });


  //Once add button is clicked
  $(document).on('click', '#clicktoadd', function() {
    //Check maximum number of input fields
    if (x < maxField) {
      x++; //Increment field counter

      // CHECK: Added this to increment number on click
      numberIncr++;

      $(".medication_info").append('<select name="pp_fileStatus' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control multipleselect pp_fileStatus dynamicVal"><option value="" disabled selected>Status</option><option value="1">Open</option><option value="2">Close</option><option value="3">Pending</option></select><p>One more dropdown. It will come from ajax</p>' + addrm);
    }
    count++;

  });
  $(document).on('change', '.pp_fileStatus', function(event) {


    if (($(this).val() == '1') || ($(this).val() == '3')) {
      $(".medication_info").append('<div class="addbankField input-wrapper padding0"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="reasonDate' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control datetimepicker" placeholder="Date"></div></div><div class="addbankField input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="reasonAmt' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control commnumber" placeholder="amt"></div></div><input type="hidden" name="remark' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control" placeholder="Remark">');
    } else {
      $(".medication_info").append('<div class="addbankField input-wrapper lbpflex padding0"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="reasonDate' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control datetimepicker" placeholder="Date"></div></div><div class="addbankField input-wrapper"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" name="remark' + numberIncr + '"  class="form-control" placeholder="Remark"></div></div><input type="hidden" name="reasonAmt' + numberIncr + '" class="form-control" placeholder="amt">');
    }
  });
  
  // CHECK: remove the below numberIncr logic
  // numberIncr++; --> remove this
});
```

```html
<div id="clicktoadd"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-bg">Add More</a></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="medication_info">
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer.

Comment: I have noticed one issue, My dropdown increment name starts from 2 and the input field starts from 3.  Is it possible to start both from 2?

Comment: please check the updated answer. if this solves your issue please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes, It's working in the snippet. I want to know what you change in the script? If I have to increment the dropdown which is coming from the ajax then what code I have to use it?

Comment: removed `numberIncr++;` which was at the end of the script and added `numberIncr++;` inside the `if` condition of `$(document).on('click')`

Comment: Give me something to implement your answer with my code.

Comment: @user9437856 what are you looking for? you want me to update with comments in code snipped on what I changed?

Comment: Your answer is working for me. You can update the comment in the snipped. I am using ajax in the scritp which is also dropdown so I am implementing the same.

Comment: I have added a comment with `// CHECK:`. Please refer to those and make changes. there is no change I have made in ajax call